# Maximum-sum subarray given constraints on indices

Tags: python, algorithm, dynamic-programming

How would I find the maximum sum of an array of unique positive integers given that some array indices cannot be paired?

For example, we have this array: [8, 2, 1, 3, 9, 4]

Elements at indices (0, 4) and (4, 5) do not like each other.

In this case, the max sum would be: 8+2+1+3+4= 18

Assuming this was on the scale of 100 entries and up to half as many constraints, how would you approach this problem?

Is there a data structure like a graph that would be useful or some DP? My main concern is with efficient runtime.

Comment: is it possible to have cycles? like having `(5,0)` too in your example?

Comment: I think this question would be better for CS.SE.

Comment: Yes cycles are possible. And sorry for the misplaced post

Comment: Sounds like an NP-hard packing problem. Try integer programming.

Comment: @KSFT, in the future, if you recommend another site, it'd be nice if you could advise the user not to cross-post and let them know how they can migrate their question if they wish.  Otherwise it leads new users down the path of cross-posting their question, which violates site rules.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are trying to solve is the [maximum-weight independent set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independent_set_(graph_theory)#Finding_independent_sets) problem. This is a problem in graph theory.

The array indices correspond to the vertices of a graph. The weight of each vertex is the array value at the respective index. In your example, vertex 0 has weight 8, and vertex 4 has weight 9.

The pairs of array indices that do not like each other correspond to the edges of the graph. For example, there is an edge between vertices 0 and 4.

You are looking for a set of array indices in which no two indices dislike each other. In terms of the graph, you want a set of of vertices in which no two vertices are connected by an edge. Such a set of vertices is called an independent set.

Among all independent sets, you want the one with the greatest sum of vertex weights. That is the maximum-weight independent set problem.

The brute-force approach to this problem tries all 2<sup>n</sup> subsets of n vertices to determine the maximum weight. Unfortunately, this problem is [NP-hard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-hard). It is believed that NP-hard problems cannot be solved in polynomial time. In other words, you can't do much better than the brute-force approach.

Comment: "you can't do much better than the brute-force approach" Common misconception. In practice, this is rather dependent on the problem and the natural inputs.

Comment: There are at most 3^(n/3) *maximal* independent sets in an n-vertex graph, and it's possible to enumerate all of them with polynomial-time *delay*.  Since the weights here are all positive, the max-weight IS is a maximal IS, so this enumeration will suffice to find it in about 2^(0.5283n)*poly(n) time.